# How to add ellipsis for highchart titles and subtitles when title has long name

Tags: highcharts

I am working on highcharts, here I am having too big titles that I need to set in smaller resolutions, So I would like to add ellipsis for highcharts title and subtitles.http://jsfiddle.net/v9n67zvx/6/

`enter code here` [1]:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set [useHTML](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/subtitle.useHTML) to true and [widthAdjust](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/subtitle.widthAdjust) to some negative value.

```
    title: {
        text: 'When chart having large text title When chart having large text title When chart having large text title',
        useHTML: true,
        widthAdjust: -200
    },
```

Override Highcharts inline style:

```
.highcharts-title, .highcharts-subtitle {
  white-space: nowrap !important;
  text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
  overflow: hidden !important
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/v9n67zvx/7/[image: ellipsis]

Comment: Thank you, It is working fine, and is their any possibility when mouse over on the title/subtitle name to show entire text in tool tip ?

Comment: Can you help me on this to get tooltip for high charts title !

Comment: You need to build tooltip from html/css and toggle its visibility on title/subtitle mouseover and mouseout - http://jsfiddle.net/j61dgu33/ https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp